# Group open bash processes to be killed together

Tags: bash, makefile, terminal, kill

I have a 4 or 5 commands being run in separate processes that i would like to be able to kill together via a script.

They are `make` commands, and I could just run `killall make` or `pkill make` but that kills other make commands I may have running.
So I'm thinking there may be a way I could open these processes as part of a group of processes, and then I could kill them as a group or loop over items in the group and kill them that way.

One way I have is to switch to a different user to open the processes and then when I kill them just kill that users session, but if there's a way to just group these processes, or hold onto there ids some how that would be great.

Any ideas?

*Let me know if more info is needed but what im hoping for is something like:*

```
openwithgroup groupname 'make command1'
openwithgroup groupname 'make command2'
openwithgroup groupname 'make command3'

# and then to kill them, maybe something like:
killgroup groupname
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store all their PIDs in an array and kill those:

```
pids=()
make command1 &
pids+=($!)
make command2 &
pids+=($!)
make command3 &
pids+=($!)

kill ${pids[@]}
```

If you are running all of these commands in the *same* script, then AFAIK the PIDs will not be reused, and you can be sure that you're [killing the correct processes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#Doing_it_right).

Comment: I think `openwithgroup` was a hypothetical command the user wanted. This answer could simply be `pids=(); make command1 & pids+=($!) ...`.

Comment: But that wasn't his actual code. "What I'm hoping for is something like ...". It was a proposed solution, not something he's currently using.